# Full and detailed list of files at a domain?

Tags: file, list, dns

I want something that creates a full list of all files/paths at a domain (mine),
including size and modification date.  I want the list to begin all the way at
the root - not just past /public_html.  I'd want to run this from my Win7 64
bit PC and have the list saved on my PC.

I do NOT want to DL all the files !

Is there a Win7-64 tool I can use to accomplish this ??

Answer (score 1):

When you say files/paths "at a domain", in general you have a misunderstanding.  A domain is basically a name that points to a resource [see here](http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/d/f/domain_name.htm).

If this sounds kind of vague, it's because it is.  Multiple computers can host a domain (ie. serve up resources for the same domain), and the resources they serve up don't have to be files at all.  You can point your browser at http:// somesite/somefile.html, and that "somefile.html" may not exist at all (yet the site could still return a webpage).

You can't (in general) list all the files/paths at a "domain", but if you have access, you can certainly do that for one or more computers.  Certain websites may provide a way to get a directory listing, but even then it would just be from the "DocumentRoot" (in Apache terms) of the website (not from root).

**EDIT:**  IF your domain is hosted on a single computer, and you have full access through ftp, you could use something like the [python script in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854572/traversing-ftp-listing) to get a remote directory listing (of this computer).  You probably need to change the line that says this:

> ftp.login()

to this:

> ftp.login(user='your username', passwd='your password')

*While it may seem like the same thing, what you're really asking for is a remote directory listing of a computer, not a domain (even if a dns lookup resolves your domain to a computer).*

Comment: I do have access - It is my domain.  I can use FTP and see everything - from the 'root' (IE - before /public_html) ... however it is very slow and I do not know if there is a way to do recursive directory listings.  Again, its mine - I can see what I want with FTP or filezilla ... just dont know of a way to capture that data.